# How to import products in host instead of database on wordpress?

Tags: database, mysql

Once I add new product in WordPress, this product adds in MySQL database
and database gets bigger and bigger after months
I would like to write post/page/products on the host instead of the database
how can I do this?
for the second question:
and how can I restore my products and posts when I change my Theme?
and we need to do another thing or not to restore our products after the change theme.
your resolve method can help me to decrease my database space and can help me to resolve my problem

Comment: the MySQL database is the most efficient way to store datas of wordpress then you don't have to worry of the database size.

Comment: @Kaperto please answer to my question if you know that, my database is too huge and I need to do that